# php db connection from another server unusual situation

Tags: php, mysql

i was trying to make a database connection from another server and i wasn't able to do it,
i was getting error instantly that can't connect to the `mysql` server,then i searched and realized that i need to forward a port, so i did and guess what happens the php page stucks for a minute on loading and after a minute error shows up and tells me that i cant connect to the server

so checkout my code

```
<?php
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("X.X.X.X","SOMEUSER","","SOMEPASS");

if(!$con)
{
echo "Failed to connect";
}
else
{
echo "Connected";
}
?>
```

i forwarded the port on 3306 on 192.168.1.9 please help!

Comment: Can you connect using the mysql client?

Comment: MySQL is using 3306
i disabled firewall and i get the message  `is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server`

and i don't know about the credentials can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would comment but don’t have enough rep to comment so an answer will have to do.

Firstly remove the credential off you post asap

Secondly Add this to your if statement.

```
echo "Error: ".mysqli_error($con);
```

It will give you more details on the problem. Im 99% sure its probably a time-out or credential issue. Attempt to connect via a mysql client. If you dont have 1, just telnet to the server on port 3306 IE telnet x.x.x.x 3306

If you don’t get a response (ie time-out) its probably a firewall issue. Else its probably a credential problem. Perhaps you only allowed that user to connect from localhost?

Comment: Once again i cannot comment on other post. That answer is leading me to believe you have not allowed the user to connect from that IP. IE in you grant command on the mysql server

`grant select on db.table to 'user'@'CONNECTING IP' identified by 'SOMEPASS';`

Comment: Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1130): Host 'ns5001871.ip-192-99-16.net' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server in /home/l2gold/public_html/test.php on line 7
Failed to connect to MySQL: Host 'ns5001871.ip-192-99-16.net' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Comment: and something ells friend  im trying to access from my web server to my pc's database how can i see what is the ip of my webserver? to put it in this user@ip identified by pass ?

Comment: @user2947710 Yip that error comes from the user only being allowed to connect from a certain location. You need to use the grant command to allow the user access. As i posted above you need to put the connecting servers ip or host name (the server where the code is sitting) after the @. A % will also do the job but i strongly advise against that considering you posted the credentials.

Comment: @user2947710

At a guess your ip is 192.99.16.76. I got that after pinging ns5001871.ip-192-99-16.net as per your last post

Comment: i use navicat and i open the console of the connection named localhost   and type CREATE USER 'web'@'192.99.16.76' IDENTIFIED BY '12345';        then i type GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON l2jesios TO 'web'@'192.99.16.76';  and in the php code i type $con=mysqli_connect("78.87.60.73","web@192.99.16.76","12345","l2jesios");    isnt this enough?

Comment: now i get access denied                                                       Warning: mysqli_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'web@192.99.16.76'@'ns5001871.ip-192-99-16.net' (using password: YES) in /home/l2gold/public_html/test.php on line 7
Failed to connect to MySQL: Access denied for user 'web@192.99.16.76'@'ns5001871.ip-192-99-16.net' (using password: YES)

Comment: Your connection string is incorrect.

`$con=mysqli_connect("78.87.60.73","web","12345","l2jesios")`

Answer (score 0):

This could be many things.

My advice is that you try to do one thing at a time to determine what's going on there.

- Is MySQL running on port 3306?
- Is the host's firewall blocking
  connections?
- Do you have the right credentials?
- Many others..

I'd also advice not to post your real credentials nor your server details on the Internet.

Comment: MySQL is using 3306
i disabled firewall and i get the message  `is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server`

and i don't know about the credentials can you help me?